# How do I export both Packet bytes and Summary line using tshark?

Tags: wireshark, export, tshark, ascii

I can export ascii using Wireshark with exactly the same settings as in the example from the [documenation](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChIOExportSection.html), i.e. Only Summary line and Packet bytes exported.

Since I have many files to do this with I suppose using tshark is way to go, but I do not understand how to do it.

Thanks,
Dick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tshark -r test.pcapng -Px > test.txt

FYI
 TShark [man-page](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html)

Comment: Thanks! Summary line is different, but it is close enough so I can parse it using Python.